Linear algebra question - what is the definition of a “distinct” eigenvalue?
I am studying university-level introductory linear algebra. This is a basic question, but I have been looking around on this and have run into nothing but confusion.
For example, the two replies to the following question appear to give two contradictory answers: How to identify distinct eigenvalues?
The first reply says:

Example. If the square matrix A has the characteristic polynomial
pA = λ(λ−1)3(λ−2)2 , then the eigenvalues of A (counted with algebraic multiplicities) are
λ1 = 0, λ2 = λ3 = λ4 = 1, λ5 = > λ6 = 2.
The distinct eigenvalues of A are 0, 1, 2.

The second reply says:

When eigenvalues are not distinct, it means that an eigenvalue appears more than once as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

The second reply seems to suggest that in the above example, the only “distinct” eigenvalue would be eigenvalue λ = 0, as this is the only one that appears exactly once in the characteristic polynomial.
So, which is it? Does “distinct” simply mean the standard English definition of ignoring duplicates; i.e., λ=0, λ=1, λ=2 in the above example would be “distinct” eigenvalues? If so, what to make of statements like “Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.” Does this sentence simply mean that any two eigenvectors will be linearly independent as long as their corresponding eigenvalues do not equal each other? (E.g., any eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue λ=1 is linearly independent with any eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue λ=2, as 1≠2.)
Or, does “distinct” eigenvalue mean the eigenvalue must appear exactly once in the characteristic polynomial (i.e., the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue must be 1). In which case, the above example has only one “distinct” eigenvalue: λ=0.
I may be overthinking this, but these contradictory definition are really confusing me. I could not find helpful info online on this, as the textbooks I found did not define “distinct.” If you reply, it would be much appreciated if you could back up your reply with a link to some textbook or academic resource! Thank you very much.

Edit: Correction and response
One correction:
I misused the term “root” in my initial post. Somehow, I thought “root” basically means “algebraic multiplicity.” (I vaguely thought the “root” of an eigenvalue is the number of times the eigenvalue appears in the characteristic polynomial.) In reality, the “roots” (a.k.a. “zeros”) of polynomial P(x) in algebra are the solutions that make P(x)=0. So, the “roots” of det(A−Iλ) are the solutions to det(A−Iλ)=0—i.e., the eigenvalues.
I’m sorry about this mistake! I have updated two paragraphs to fix this. I hope this correction makes the initial post more clear.
Response to answers/comments:
All the answers and comments have been helpful so far. In particular:

This comment helped me realize my mistake with the term “root.”
This comment points out that there are two slightly different usages of the term “distinct” in this context: “the eigenvalues are distinct,” meaning they are all different, and “the distinct eigenvalues,” meaning the set of eigenvalues (ignoring multiplicity). I had a vague notion similar to this in my head, but this really helped me to “get” it.

Much appreciation to all who have contributed!

"Distinct" is being used in two different senses in the two answers to the question you linked.

In the second reply of that post, "...an eigenvalue appears more than once as a root of the characteristic polynomial" doesn't refer to having a root of 1.
When counting distinct eigenvalues, we are just counting how many different eigenvalues there are. i.e., we follow the English definition of 'ignoring duplicates'

The word "distinct" only makes sense for two or more things. You can say "the eigenvalues are all distinct" but you can't say "the eigenvalue $1$ is distinct". When we say the eigenvalues are distinct, we mean all of them are different. When we say "the distinct eigenvalues", we are using the word in a slightly different way - we don't mean "the eigenvalues that are distinct" (which doesn't make sense), we mean "the set of eigenvalues" (ignoring multiplicity.)

I suggest using "distinct" in the first case and "simple" in the second case.

I guess distinct just mean without counting multiplicities. That is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1$, $\lambda_4=\lambda_5=2$, then we have distinct eigenvalue is $\lambda_1,\lambda_4$ (since we do not count multiplicity), so we write $1,2$ as the distinct eigenvalues.

The set of distinct eigenvalues of a matrix/linear operator is the set of all the eigenvalues, without repeating any of them. Which means if a matrix has solutions of the characteristics polynomial as ={1,1,1,2,2,3}, then set of distinct eigenvalues would be {1,2,3} only.

Elements of a set are distinct by definition. OP's linguistic question is answered in the comments.

The usual use of this language in linear algebra books is something like this: “A matrix with distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable.” The intent is that all the eigenvalues are distinct — the $n$ eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix are $n$ different numbers.
